# I need help getting powershell to run c# code

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, powershell, error

I found a technet blog saying you could run c# code in powershell, so I ended up giving it a try. When I try to run the following powershell script I get 2 errors and I'm not sure how to resolve them. Does anyone know the fix for the errors below?

Technet Blog: [Using CSharp (C#) code in Powershell scripts](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$Assem = {
    "Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
         }

$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System.IO;

namespace TurnAlertsOnOff
{
    class onOff
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #code goes here.


        }
    }
}
"@


Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp

[TurnAlertsOnOff.onOff]::Main()
```

Error 1

```
Add-Type : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\test.ps1:115 char:1
+ Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Error 2 (Not caused by first error.)

```
Unable to find type [TurnAlertsOnOff.onOff]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\test.ps1:117 char:1
+ [TurnAlertsOnOff.onOff]::Main()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (TurnAlertsOnOff.onOff:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: Can you include a link to the blog?

Comment: Added the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I've ran C# within PowerShell, I've done the assembly bit differently (I'm in O365, so only use CSOM):

```
$path = "path to folder containing dll's (e.g.,ISAPI folder in 15 Hive)"
$assemblies = @(
    "$path\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll",
    "$path\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
    "System.Core"
)

$cSharp = @"
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;

namespace SPClient
{
    public class SharePointPS
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Code here
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies
[SPClient.SharePointPS]::Main()
```

Never had any issues with it.  `System.Management.Automation` and `System.Security` were used for handling the O365 authentication, so they are not necessary for you.

Comment: Thanks I changed the structure of my assembly and Add-Type and it resolved the first error. Now I need to figure out way I'm getting the second error.

Comment: Try specifing the class and function as public class/method

Comment: So the path would be: `$path = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI"`

Comment: @Underverse Yes, that should be the path.